# Flutter: Place a particular widget in a row at center

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

How to place the "question mark" at center of row?
Expected result is "?" are all at center regardless of the values on left/right.

[image: Expected Result]

```
      body: ListView.builder(
      itemCount: testList.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return Card(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    color: Colors.green,
                    child: Text(testList[index].n1.toString(), style: TextStyle(fontSize: 80,)),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    color: Colors.red,
                    child: Text(testList[index].x, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 80,)),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    color: Colors.green,
                    child: Text(testList[index].n2.toString(), style: TextStyle(fontSize: 80, )),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Text('>'),
              Text('<'),
              Text('='), //
            ],
          ),
        );
      }),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use row and Expanded with flex widget to achieve your desire output.

Following minimal code help you more.

```
Card(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                flex: 1,
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Expanded(child: Container()),
                    Container(
                      color: Colors.green,
                      child: Text('10',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 80,
                          )),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                color: Colors.red,
                child: Text("?",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 80,
                    )),
              ),
              Expanded(
                flex: 1,
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      color: Colors.green,
                      child: Text('100',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 80,
                          )),
                    ),
                    Expanded(child: Container()),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Text('>'),
          Text('<'),
          Text('='), //
        ],
      ),
    )
```

Comment: Thanks. middle/center should have a flex =1

Comment: this will work without even flex i think. flex used when you want to divide expanded widget's size in different ratio. for example if you give any expanded widget flex:2 and other's flex:1 then first widget will take double space then other one.